# ASP.NET MVC (System.Web.Mvc) : is the OutputCacheAttribute class affected by the IIS "Cache size limit (in MB)" parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, system.web

Let's say I'm using server-side caching with the `OutputCacheAttribute` attribute as follows:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 86400, Location = System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
```

Is it impacted by the IIS "Cache size limit (in MB)" parameter (in Output Caching) ?

It seems that it's not the case, but I would like to find a way to configure the maximum size of the cache used by this attribute (at the application or global level, whichever is applicable).

Comment: _"at the application or global level"_ - they're both the same thing

Comment: So let's say at the application pool level associated with the site or at the IIS level.

Comment: As long as your application is published to iis, it will definitely be limited by Output Caching.